# Have to type exit() every time in visual studio code terminal before running python program again?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, exit

I am using visual studio code to run a simple program, but every time I run the program in terminal, once it is finished it gets stuck as if I am still in python in the terminal. I say this because it leaves me with the three arrows after I finish the program.

">>>"

(i.e. I need to go down to the integrated terminal window in VSC and type exit() before I run the program again or it will throw invalid syntax errors because VSC is trying to use bash command line commands while I am still in python.

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjSuS.png)

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: That's what the `-i` argument does.

Comment: I run the code using either the run button in the top right of the GUI or I right click on the script and click "run python file in terminal"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can select `Run Python File in Terminal` instead of `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`, equals click the run button on the top-left of the VSCode.

And if you want to get out of python, you can take the shortcut of `Ctrl+Z` too.

Comment: I am already running it this way, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Aaron Selnick Sorry, but I think you have selected `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`, which will execute the python code in the REPL mode.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am indeed clicking "run python file in terminal". Clicking run selection/line in python terminal runs just the line that my cursor happens to be next to.

Comment: @Aaron Selnick Sorry, but `in terminal` and `in python terminal` is different, could you provide a screenshot of it? and does `Ctrl+Z` work?